# Calculate gamma using 3 dimensional array matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix as below and sample size is 10.

```
vt=matrix(1:30, ncol=3) 
n=10 
gamma<- array(0, dim=c(3,3,(n-2)))
for (j in 1:(n-2)){
gamma[,,j]<-(1/n)*(t(vt[(j+1):(n-1),])%*%vt[j:(n-2),]
}ter code here
```

And I am trying to calculate gamma using array function as above, but it is not working.
what I want to have is a 3 by 3 matrix for gamma 1 to (n-2) using those code above.

For example,
`gamma[,,1]=(1/n)*(t(vt[2:(n-1),])%*%vt[1:(n-2),] which is a 3 by 3 matrix.
gamma[,,2]=(1/n)*(t(vt[3:(n-1),])%*%vt[2:(n-2),] which is a 3 by 3 matrix.
gamma[,,3]=(1/n)*(t(vt[4:(n-1),])%*%vt[3:(n-2),] which is a 3 by 3 matrix.`
and so on....

Do you have idea how to fix the code above?

Comment: It is not working. ...means what? If it's just the missing parenthesis then please get a better editor and delete this example of user error.

Comment: I am sorry that I made you confused...I edited the question. @BondedDust

Answer (score 0):

```
vt=matrix(1:30, ncol=3) 
n=10 
gamma<- array(0, dim=c(3,3,(n-2)))
for (j in 1:(n-2)){
gamma[,,j]<-(1/n)*t(vt[(j+1):(n-1),])%*%vt[j:(n-2),]
}
```

I think I figured it out.
now this code is working.